# Make an addition of two IEnumerable with linq

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, ienumerable, addition

I would like to make an addition of two IEnumerable using Linq

example :

```
class Calcul
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Add(IEnumerable<int> firstList, 
                                       IEnumerable<int> secondList)
    {
    }
}
```

In the Add function, I would like to make an addition of the members from these lists and I know that is possible to reduce in a single line by using Linq (lambda expression). I would like to know how to.

Thanks.

Comment: Given lists `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}`, do you intend to concatenate the lists together (resulting in `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`) or sum the matching elements together (resulting in `{5, 7, 9}`)?

Comment: It's sum and not to concatenate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
return firstList.Zip(secondList, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx)

```
var result = firstList.Concat(secondList);
```

If you want to create anew list, you can use `Enumerable.ToList`:

```
List<int> both = result.ToList();
```

If you want to remove duplicates, you can use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) instead of `Concat`.